# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, request, interpreter

I can't seem to run this code in python 3.7.7

```
import panda as pd 

all_data = pd.read_csv('gas_prices.csv')

print(all_data)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/HP/Desktop/VSc Code/Understanding pand/Sales_analysis/sale_data.py", line 1, in <module>
    import panda as pd
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\panda\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from request import PandaRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

I try to change the interpreter but it doesn't seem to make a difference and I don't think I'm in a virtual environment.

This was working a few days ago but suddenly this error started appearing.

Comment: It is `pandas` not `panda`. `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 1):

accourding to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/request/) use : pip install request

Answer (score 1):

You've manually installed part of pandas and accidentally named it "panda". Instead use the tool `pip`, which in Python 3.7.7 is included. Like so:

```
C:\> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe install pandas
```

Good luck!

Comment: can't believe i made such a silly mistake, thank you so much!